# How to use both Vue-Router and Gorilla Mux Router

Tags: vue.js, go, routes, vue-router, vue-cli

I started to create a web app using Vue JS as the front end framework. In this process, I'm using Vue-Router to route paths to my vue components. And I'm serving this web app using Go with gorilla mux as my router.

Here I am not able to load any component to `<router-view></router-view>` in `App.vue`.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144883/vue-router-in-production-serving-with-go). And I tried removing `mode: 'history'` but no luck. In the comments, it was mentioned that he let Go redirect all not-found URLs to `/# + r.URL.Path`. I didn't understand this bit.

I'll appreciate if anyone can guide me with some example.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, don't serve the front end from within the Go app. Here's what I do:

Go app is the backend, provides RESTful APIs for the front end to use.

There's a nginx server setup as a reverse proxy for the Go app.

nginx serves the front end directly

I use nginx to serve the Go    backend in a certain url location or different port

Comment: `If possible, don't serve the front end from within the Go app.` why ?

Comment: Static content should served through a CDN or at least through nginx directly. Because nginx or a CDN would be more performant than a Go app. I don't want my Go functions executing for serving a simple css file.